# How to get live stream url from youtube live?

Tags: youtube, inputstream

I have a link live stream from youtube: https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/upn/V377i0zgS9U/id/iGTIK_8ydoI.1/itag/0/gcr/vn/pmbypass/yes/expire/1429081762/sver/3/keepalive/yes/playlist_type/LIVE/source/yt_live_broadcast/maudio/1/signature/648757B5224BB06A23DADA58D1D514F8465B5B01.BEA5B2EE61132AB1A1768E9852B12F6DD641322F/ip/192.168.1.1/key/yt5/ipbits/0/ratebypass/yes/fexp/3300112%2C3300133%2C3300137%2C3300161%2C3310698%2C3311881%2C900720%2C907263%2C916656%2C932627%2C932631%2C934954%2C938028%2C9405998%2C9407115%2C9408031%2C9408163%2C9408347%2C9408708%2C9408732%2C947233%2C947243%2C948124%2C948703%2C951703%2C952612%2C952626%2C952637%2C954815%2C957201%2C961404%2C961406/hfr/1/sparams/gcr%2Chfr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmaudio%2Cplaylist_type%2Cpmbypass%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire/file/index.m3u8

I got this link from page source, but when I cannot restream it with ffmpeg/ffplay, this is error message:
*[tcp @ 0000000004442220] Failed to resolve hostname manifest.googlevideo.com: Th
e name does not resolve for the supplied parameters*
https://......the/above/link...index.m3u8: Input/Output error

Does anyone help me find exactly live streaming link from youtube?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube as of now does not provide you the opportunity to get a direct URL to your live stream. I researched this for a long time as I wanted to put my LIVE Stream on ROKU a streaming device. YouTube however is on Roku well because they are YouTube. But do let me know if you find a way around this.